# AWS CDK: How should I attach an ECS service to an existing load balancer?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer, infrastructure-as-code

I have a pre-existing load balancer on AWS, and I would like to spin a stack with an ECS service that is targeted by that load balancer.

I found [this solution](https://towardsthecloud.com/aws-cdk-alb-fargate-service) that suggests using an [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html); however, that construct only works creating a new listener, while I want to use the existing listener (or should I want a new listener?).

Reading the source code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v2.126.0/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns/lib/fargate/application-load-balanced-fargate-service.ts#L37) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v2.126.0/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns/lib/base/application-load-balanced-service-base.ts), I tried to use the same functions for the looked-up listener, but apparently cdk "Cannot add default Target Groups to imported ApplicationListener" (from cdk errors).

My best attempt at the moment:

```js
// cdk-stack.js inside the constructor
let service = new ecs.FargateService(this, id + '-service', {
  serviceName: id + '-service',
  cluster: cluster,
  taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
  securityGroups: [thisSecurityGroup],
});

const loadBalancer = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromLookup(this, 'bip-lb', { loadBalancerArn: loadBalancerArn });

const listener = elbv2.ApplicationListener.fromLookup(this, 'https-listener', {
  loadBalancerArn: loadBalancer.loadBalancerArn,
  listenerProtocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
  listenerPort: 443,
});

const targetGroup = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, id + '-target-group', {
  targetGroupName: id + '-target-group',
});

listener.addTargetGroups(id + '-target-group', {targetGroups: [targetGroup]});

targetGroup.addTarget(service);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `priority` prop to `listener.addTargetGroups`.  Under the hood, the method creates a new [ApplicationListenerRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListenerRule.html) construct.  The rule requires an explicit `priority`.

For this reason, the CDK throws the observed error when `addTargetGroups` does not have a `priority` prop defined..

Comment: Thanks! This solves the immediate error, but when deploying it gets stuck on the service and fails because it took too much time.

Comment: @Gabriele Glad to help.  Sounds like my answer solved your posted problem, but that your stack has other, orthogonal issues. I suggest opening a new question with the details of the ECS problem.